# laravel change error report without messing in base code?

Tags: php, laravel, error-handling

This is my first post in stack overflow, so if I do something wrong, please notify me.

So, I'm developing a platform for a client and we are short on time for the delivery phases, so,  in order to get everything done in time I want to change the error reporting level in production.

In order to achieve this, I went to: vendor > laravel > framework > src > Illuminate > Foundation > Bootstrap > HandleExceptions.php - Line : 27 ( I think ) and replaced :

```
error_reporting(-1);

set_error_handler([$this, 'handleError']);

set_exception_handler([$this, 'handleException']);

register_shutdown_function([$this, 'handleShutdown']);
```

By:

```
if(env('APP_DEBUG') == true) {
    error_reporting(-1);

    set_error_handler([$this, 'handleError']);

    set_exception_handler([$this, 'handleException']);

    register_shutdown_function([$this, 'handleShutdown']);

}else{
    set_error_handler(null);
    set_exception_handler(null);
}
```

Everything works like a charm but I want to keep my good practices in check and avoid completelly to mess with base code.

Any one has a sugestion on how may I override this error reporting ( except by doing it on every blade layout - I want to keep code repetition to a minimum )

**Resuming the question:** 
 - I want to set_error_handler(null);set_exception_handler(null);
 - The reason is: we are thight on schedule and with a complicated project ( lots of relationships )
 - I've allready solved the problem by declaring it on the framework itself or in every blade page. But in order to keep good coding practices, I don't want to mess with the framework and I want to avoid code repetition.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Most people would consider suppressing errors and "keep good coding practices" to be mutually exclusive.

Comment: Sure, but let's make it this way. I have at this point a platform with allmost 500 methods implemented in 2 weeks. We and the client agreed to keep error reporting off because he made it clear that it's imperative to have a minimum viable product working. So we are keeping that part

Comment: Suppressing errors doesn't change a broken product into a minimum viable product, it just makes it a broken product that doesn't even tell you when it fails. And arguably, that's much worse!

Comment: Which version of Laravel are you using?

Comment: Right Nick I can't argue with that, but just because I have zero reputation on stackoverflow that doesn't mean I'm not into this game for a while. I've been coding for professionally for 9+ years and a few others just because I love it so, I'm totally aware of everything you are telling me at this point. that said: 

The client wants to present this to a restrict audience and he wants to show the platform running, they want to see it running and a screen display full of errors because a undefined offset for example, it's a major turn off at this point.

Comment: So, now we have to make it work, then we will have time to make it shine even so, I'd like to stick with some rules, like this one, to avoid messy situations I had in the past. This question is for learning purposes only. If I have to turn error reporting off, I'd like to know if there is any way to do it before messing with the framework. 

Just that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you probably know, there's various different types of error in PHP: http://php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.constants.php

For fatal / non-recoverable errors, you probably want to keep the Laravel error handling. The alternative is your users simply see a blank white page, which isn't at all helpful, so I'd suggest you leave the actual error and exception handlers intact.

The [`error_reporting()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) function changes *which* errors get reported. The value of `-1` used by Laravel means report *all* errors. When you bypassed that line with your modification, the error reporting level falls back to whatever is set in your `php.ini` config. You want to set error reporting to always be this level.

So, **how to override the level of `error_reporting` as set by Laravel?**

You can simply call `error_reporting()` again, after Laravel, and set it to whatever level you want. It sounds like you probably want something like:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE & ~E_STRICT & ~E_DEPRECATED & ~E_WARNING);
```

**Where should you put that?**

Anywhere where it will run *after* Laravel has set up its error reporting, and *before* your erroneous code runs. The exact locations may vary, depending on the version of Laravel. For 5.x, perhaps in the `boot()` method of `AppServiceProvider`?

Comment: Now that's the answer I'd like to ear. I'm running 5.2.
I'll try after the boot and set your answer as accepted if it works

Answer (score 1):

I think that you can use the App:error of laravel for handle the errors.

On your `app/start/global.php` , you can put this:

```
App::error(function(Exception $exception)
{
    Log::error($exception);
});
```

And you can handle all the error from laravel and do whatever you want when they happens.

You will have more information at https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/errors#handling-errors

**Update: This one is for laravel 5.0**

```
public function report(Exception $e)
{
    if ($e instanceof CustomException) {
        //
    }

    return parent::report($e);
}
```

You will have more information at https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/errors#handling-errors

Comment: Tried alllready, none of them work. I continue to have Undefined offset exceptions